# eslint-plugin-import for ordering by package name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I already my imports in the following order: react first, external packages, codebase, current directory

so for example

```
import * as React from "react"
import { css } from "emotion"
import a from "hooks" // this lives below emotion because I want to sort on package name

import Form from "my/own/component/path" // notice I also want gap between these imports

import Something from "./something" // import from current directory
```

how would I right a rule using `eslint-plugin-import` to do this?

I have something like this so far:

```
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          "caseInsensitive": true,
          "order": "asc"
        },
        "groups": ["external", "builtin", "parent", ["sibling", "index"]],
        "newlines-between": "never",
        "pathGroups": [
          {
            "group": "external",
            "pattern": "react",
            "position": "before"
          },
          {
            "group": "builtin",
            "pattern": "**",
            "position": "after"
          },
          {
            "group": "external",
            "pattern": "./**",
            "position": "after"
          }
        ],
        "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["builtin"]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: whats not working for you?

Comment: it's saying `@apollo` should be before react and it's not complaining when I remove the space between imports